# How can I setup images like this?

Tags: image

On the website: http://www.polygon.com/  they have like images floating around the top of the page.  I keep thinking about it but I can't seem to figure out the code on how to set up images to look like that and cover the screen perfectly and fit on all screen monitors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this:

```
<div class="somediv">
    <img src="someimage.png">
    <img src="someimage.png">
</div>
```

And then have the stylesheet like this:

```
div.somediv {
    margin:0;
}

div.somediv img {
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
    height: 50vw;
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0eegvrp7/

The main point is the `float:left` part.

Comment: Thanks so much; I wish nothing but happiness towards your way.